# inorder traversal in ruby only print root note

Tags: ruby, algorithm, data-structures

My code is:

```
class Tree
  attr_accessor :node, :left, :right

  def initialize(*args)
    self.node = args[0]
    self.left = args[1]
    self.right = args[2]
  end

  def inorder
    if self.left
      self.left.inorder
    else
      return
    end
    puts self.node
    if self.right
      self.right.inorder
    else
      return
    end
  end
end

t2 = Tree.new 2
t1 = Tree.new 1
t  = Tree.new 3,t1,t2
t.inorder
```

which only prints root node 3. What goes wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your code will `return` before `puts`.

```
  def inorder
    if self.left
      self.left.inorder
    end
    puts self.node
    if self.right
      self.right.inorder
    end
  end
```